# Plotly, streamlit: how to keep the fullscreen view

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I am building the choropleth map regarding the vaccination rate over the world. To plot with sequential color, I use `Plotly` to plot the map, and use `streamlit` to render the map on the webpage with Python. However, the map is too small, I've tried the `fig.update_layout()` to adjust the size, but the map is not centered. The "view fullscreen" on the toolbar exactly solves my problem as it's centered and always fits the screen. Thus, is there any way to keep it fullscreen?

Here is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

vaccination_data = pd.read_csv('vaccinations.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(vaccination_data)

def vaccination_lastest_date_by_country(df):
  return df.groupby('location').last().reset_index()

country_lastest_vaccination = vaccination_lastest_date_by_country(df)

df_vaccination_by_country = country_lastest_vaccination.sort_values(by='total_vaccinations_per_hundred', ascending=True)

fig = px.choropleth(df_vaccination_by_country, locations="iso_code",
                    color="total_vaccinations_per_hundred", 
                    hover_name="location",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma) # should be able to adjust the color

fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width= 1200, height=800) # map not centered

st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

The data is public: https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/vaccinations/README.md

Comment: Try `st.plotly_chart(fig,height=800)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work using @Pluviophile comment,  `use_container_width=True` and `st.set_page_config(layout="wide")`. I did use one of the [chloropleth examples](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) in order to get data to show.

```py
fig.update_layout(title_text="title", margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0}, height=800)
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

[image: A chloropleth map that fits the screen both in height and in width]

The entirety of the code is as follows:

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px


st.set_page_config(
    layout="wide",
)

with urlopen(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json"
) as response:
    counties = json.load(response)


df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
    dtype={"fips": str},
)


fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=counties,
    locations="fips",
    color="unemp",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    range_color=(0, 12),
    scope="usa",
    labels={"unemp": "unemployment rate"},
)
fig.update_layout(title_text="title", margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0}, height=800)
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```